# Bot Composer and BotBuilder FacebookAdapter resulting in "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: botframework

I am using MS Bot Composer combined with BotBuilder Facebook Adapter in order to post my bot following the "new" rules of Facebook Workplace - important to remember that I've already tried to use this directly on Facebook Messenge, same situation applies.

The integration and connection works fine, the problem now is to understand how to post anything apart from text.

An example below of an attempt to get the correct template

````
# channelData
-```{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"What do you want to do next?",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"https://www.messenger.com",
            "title":"Visit Messenger"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}```
````

[image]

And then, the bot's answer:

[image]

Comment: [Linking](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/5049#issuecomment-754160777)

Comment: There are a lot of moving parts here so you will need to help us reproduce this behavior. When you mention the new rules of Facebook Workplace, do you mean you were previously using the Facebook connector and now must switch to the Facebook adapter? Have you integrated the Facebook adapter using an ejected runtime? Can you link to documentation you've followed about getting the Facebook adapter to work with Composer? Can you link to documentation regarding the LG format you've used for the channel data?

Comment: 1st question: Yes. Workplace does not allow integrations using facebook.botframework.com and recommend to use the Adapter. 2nd: Yes. A dotnet runtime. 3rd: There is no official docs. Just a guide by a Composer dev to a similar error. [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/2705#issuecomment-664230948). 4rd: Again, just a guide. [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/2618#issuecomment-611344740). 

This is the final JSON I am sending to Facebook: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/BJ7iAY20).

Comment: Just to inform that if I use the same ChannelData without the adapter, everything works fine. Maybe I am missing some libraries for the adapter... If you need more tests, lemme know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go the channel data route, the Facebook adapter expects you to provide a full `FacebookMessage` object as the channel data. That's one level up from the JSON you've provided, so it would look like this:

```json
{
  "message":{
    "attachment":{
      "type":"template",
      "payload":{
        "template_type":"button",
        "text":"What do you want to do next?",
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"https://www.messenger.com",
            "title":"Visit Messenger"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, that won't work because it's missing the other properties a `FacebookMessage` needs, like `sender`. Rather than trying to populate the full Facebook message, it may be easier to just go the attachment route instead of the channel data route. You can see how to do that in the [Facebook adapter sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/61.facebook-adapter/Bots/EchoBot.cs#L83-L92):

> ```cs
> private static Attachment CreateTemplateAttachment(string filePath)
> {
>     var templateAttachmentJson = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
>     var templateAttachment = new Attachment()
>     {
>         ContentType = "template",
>         Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(templateAttachmentJson),
>     };
>     return templateAttachment;
> }
> ```

In Composer, you can set the activity's attachments instead of its channel data. Just set the content type to "template" and the content to the payload of the attachment you have now, using the [Facebook adapter sample's resources](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/61.facebook-adapter/Resources) as a guide:

````
# attachment
- ```
{
  "contentType": "template",
  "content": {
    "template_type": "button",
    "text": "What do you want to do next?",
    "buttons": [
      {
        "type": "web_url",
        "url": "https://www.messenger.com",
        "title": "Visit Messenger"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```
````

You can see how the Facebook adapter treats both channel data and attachments by having a look at the [`FacebookHelper`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Adapters/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Adapters.Facebook/FacebookHelper.cs) class.

Comment: Just answered your reply, Kyle.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you mean. Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Unfortunately not... My answer got deleted here, do you have any contact to reach you?

Comment: It's better for me to answer your questions publicly so my answers can help more people. Can you explain why my answer isn't acceptable?

Comment: I am using Azure Functions... Now in Composer, I have [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/BgjrxBFw), [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/v3JWariw) is the JSON I am sending to Workplace. In `Startup.cs` I inserted the line with AddTransient [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/3UDGmPCU), then I created a `Bot.cs` [file](https://pastebin.com/raw/dsmS8zL0) and then this is the answer from Workplace: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr7FQ.png)

Comment: Why are you trying to set the content type of the activity? The activity has no `contentType` property. You need to use the `contentType` property of the attachment. I've edited my answer to show what that would look like.

Comment: Whatever I insert, it seems that it goes directly inside the property "content" of the attachment. Maybe I dont need to parse to JSON inside Composer.

Comment: I've finally found a way to implement it. We need to overwrite the "contentType" by using the function ActivityAttachment. For example: ${ActivityAttachment(json(test()),"template")}

Comment: Go ahead and upvote and accept this answer. If you need help with quick replies then you can ask a new question